# How to remove the last character from a string contained within an html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have spans that contain words, and I'd like to figure out how to remove the last character using jquery.  For instance:

```
<span>text inside</span>
```

would then be:

```
<span>text insid</span>
```

I thought it would be as simple as something like

```
$('span').last().remove();
```

But it doesn't seem like that works.  It just removes the whole span element.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You can do `const newString = someString.slice(0, -1)` to get the string without the last character.

Comment: What do you mean "seem"? If you're using functions, don't guess at what they do, [look them up](https://api.jquery.com/last/). The `last()` function has nothing to do with text, so what on earth made you assume it was the right function to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery [text(function)](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) is probably the least amount of code to do it.

When function given as argument it will iterate all in selector collection and expose the current text as second argument

```js
$('span').text((_, txt) => txt.slice(0,-1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>text inside</span><br/>
<span>Another span</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla Javascript:

```
let val = document.querySelectorAll("span");

val.forEach(item => {
  item.textContent = item.textContent.slice(0, -1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would edit the text contents not the DOM elements itself

```
tmp = $('span').text();
$('span').text(tmp.substring(0,tmp.length -1));
```

Comment: Actually not a good approach since `text()` actually returns one concatenated  string for all elements in the collection. One of the oddities in jQuery getters

Comment: OP only has one span element, so i guess this would be perfectly fine, of course you need the correct selector

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
// Can use tage name, id and class (span, #span, .span)
function removeLast(objName){
obj = document.querySelector(objName);
objVal = obj.innerHTML;
length = objVal.length;
obj.innerHTML = objVal.substr(0, length - 1);
}
removeLast("span");
removeLast("#id");
removeLast(".class");
```

HTML:

```
<span>Test Only Tag</span><br/>  
<span id="id">Test Only ID</span><br/>  
<span class="class">Test Only Class</span><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like:

```js
$(function(){
$.fn.extend({removeLastChar:function(count = 1){
  return this.each(function(i, e){
    if(e.value)e.value = e.value.slice(0, -count);
    if(e.textContent)e.textContent = e.textContent.slice(0, -count);
  });
}});
$('#test1').removeLastChar(); $('#test2').removeLastChar();
console.log($('#test3').removeLastChar(4).val());
}); // end load
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test1'>This is Test #1</div>
<input id='test2' type='text' value='This is the Second Test' />
<button value='just a test' id='test3'>This should work too!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQUERY to get the `length` elements `text()`, then `splice()` the string using the length - 1. This will remove the last character in the string...

```js
// For multiple elements, you can use a loop to target the element you desire to affect.

let $span = $( "span" );
$span.each(function(){   
     console.log($(this).text().slice( 0, -1 ));
});


// or you could reference the key in an each loop
// below I will target the third element in the list using its key => `2`

$.each( $span, function( key, value ) {
   if(key === 2){
       console.log( key + ": " + value.textContent.slice(0, -1) );
   }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>text inside</span><br>
<span>text inside is different</span><br>
<span>this is the text inside</span><br>
<span>more text inside</span><br>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Simple answer to OP question without any reference to keys just grabbing the elements tag using jquery and slicing the text()...

```js
let slice = $( "span" ).text().slice( 0, -1 );
console.log(slice);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>text inside</span>
```

Comment: Add another span to demo will see a big flaw

Comment: charlietfl, OP did not post multiple span tags, though I have added other options that show multiple elements and how to target a specific one...

Answer (score 0):

Single line solution:

```
$('span').html($('span').html().substr(0, $('span').html().length-1));
```

Comment: With multiple spans all will end up with same text, try it

Comment: True, but that's a matter of the selector. In the original question there was only one span, and all the other answers assumed there aren't more.